# Jackrabbit - Select node with maximum property value

Tags: xpath, jackrabbit, jcr-sql2

Let's say I have several *file* nodes with a property called foo. In Jackrabbit the xpath query I use to find those nodes by a property value is as follows:

```
/jcr:root/content/*[jcr:uuid='9b3d22fc-2354-49a6-afd0-9b672ae5a553']//file[foo = 10] order by @score
```

An oversimplified and raw representation of my repository as XML would look like this:

```
<content>
    <formNode jcrUuid="9b3d22fc-2354-49a6-afd0-9b672ae5a553">
        <year>
            <month>
                <day>
                    <hour>
                        <min>
                            <file foo="4"></file>
                            <file foo="10"></file>
                        </min>
                    </hour>
                </day>
                <day>
                    <hour>
                        <min>
                            <file foo="10"></file>
                        </min>
                        <min>
                            <file foo="5"></file>
                        </min>
                    </hour>
                    <hour>
                        <min>
                            <file foo="6"></file>
                        </min>
                    </hour>
                </day>
            </month>
        </year>
    </formNode>
</content>
```

Now. How can I find all the *file* nodes with the maximum value of foo? Does anyone know how to do this either by using xpath or JCR_SQL2?

I've tried the following queries without success:

1. Returns all the file nodes under the provided jcr:uuid

   ```
   /jcr:root/content/*[jcr:uuid='9b3d22fc-2354-49a6-afd0-9b672ae5a553']//file[not(../file/foo > foo)] order by @score
   ```
2. Throws an Exception

   ```
   jcr:root/content/*[jcr:uuid='9b3d22fc-2354-49a6-afd0-9b672ae5a553']//file[not(//file/foo > foo)] order by @score
   ```

   Exception:

   ```
   javax.jcr.query.InvalidQueryException: Unsupported root level query node: org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.query.RelationQueryNode@8fedc
   ```

I've also tried the function **fn:max**. But AFAIK this is a XPATH 2.0 feature, which is not supported by JackRabbit 2.2.13, and I'm forced to use this version of JackRabbit.

Comment: What does the XML that you are querying look like? Specifically just a few foo nodes to see what "the maximum value of foo" might be.

Comment: Hi @LegoStormtroopr. What I can add to my post is a raw representation of what my repository would look like if wee see it as XML. Or the directory tree structure representation of it.